# text area getting accurate cursor position on resize

Tags: javascript, html

I've textarea with no limit of maxlength. As default thing, it displays text in multiple line. Currently it is as follows:

- on focus [using mouse pointer], text should move into one line
- the cursor position should capture
- Textarea height to become auto
- the cursor position should move at captured place
- and it should be viewed in the textarea

Can I achieve the same without using `setTimeout()`. Tried many ways but didn't get output as expected without using `setTimeout()`.

Any suggestions and comments are highly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
$('textarea').focus(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('textarea').css({
      'height': 'auto',
      'white-space': 'nowrap'
    });
    $('textarea')[0].scrollLeft 
      = (
          $('textarea')[0].selectionStart 
          * (
            $('textarea')[0].scrollWidth / $('textarea').val().length
          )
        ) - 20;
  }, 1);
});
$('textarea').blur(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'white-space': 'normal'
  });
  $(this).css({
    'height': $(this)[0].scrollHeight + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
textarea#workingTA {
  resize: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  direction: ltr;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="workingTA" cols="35"></textarea>
```

Comment: As I understand it: Your issue boils down to the fact that you the `selectionStart` value is always zero, if you directly measure it in your `focus` EventListener, but is calulated correctly, if you do it in a setTimeout. Is this correct?

Comment: Try the `click()` event listener instead of the `focus()` event listener

Comment: @yunzen, yeah that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `click` listener, not the `focus` listener

Also I did some refactoring of your code :)

```js
;(function() {
  var click = function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var $el = $(el);
    el.classList.remove('normal')
    el.classList.add('auto')

    $el.height('auto')
    el.scrollLeft = el.selectionStart * el.scrollWidth / $el.val().length - $(el).width() / 2;
  }
  
  var blur = function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var $el = $(el);
    el.classList.add('normal')
    el.classList.remove('auto')
    
    $el.height(el.scrollHeight)

  }
  
  $(document)
    // this is the important part: 'click' works, but 'focus' doesn't
    .on('click', 'textarea', click)
    .on('blur', 'textarea', blur)
  ;
  $(window)
    .on('load', function() {
      $('textarea').trigger('blur')
    })
  ;
})();
```

```css
textarea.workingTA {
  resize: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  direction: ltr;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

textarea.auto {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

textarea.normal {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="workingTA" class="workingTA normal" cols="35">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam venenatis congue consequat. Aenean tortor erat, euismod ut elit vitae, placerat efficitur magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus egestas pulvinar lacus nec varius. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce risus risus, luctus eget purus ut, consequat viverra dolor. Pellentesque euismod, nisl eu rhoncus facilisis, ligula ligula fringilla mauris, a tempor tortor mi eget augue. Ut at semper turpis. Fusce lectus lectus, finibus eu imperdiet eget, dictum ac nisl. Aliquam at dapibus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum interdum blandit lectus, id rhoncus dolor imperdiet id. Phasellus condimentum lacinia sapien non mattis. Nulla a lectus nisi. Aenean et nunc vel nibh pulvinar blandit. Nulla eget dictum leo. Curabitur elementum purus non erat pharetra pharetra. Ut et ante eget diam eleifend porttitor. Ut convallis leo ac urna ultricies scelerisque sed ac odio. Phasellus vehicula tempor varius. Donec accumsan ullamcorper ultrices. Maecenas nec luctus arcu. Proin non odio libero. Cras vitae nisi scelerisque, ullamcorper eros volutpat, euismod nibh. Nam diam orci, elementum vel sapien nec, mattis auctor quam.
</textarea>


<textarea id="workingTA2" class="workingTA normal" cols="35">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam venenatis congue consequat. Aenean tortor erat, euismod ut elit vitae, placerat efficitur magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus egestas pulvinar lacus nec varius. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce risus risus, luctus eget purus ut, consequat viverra dolor. Pellentesque euismod, nisl eu rhoncus facilisis, ligula ligula fringilla mauris, a tempor tortor mi eget augue. Ut at semper turpis. Fusce lectus lectus, finibus eu imperdiet eget, dictum ac nisl. Aliquam at dapibus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum interdum blandit lectus, id rhoncus dolor imperdiet id. Phasellus condimentum lacinia sapien non mattis. Nulla a lectus nisi. Aenean et nunc vel nibh pulvinar blandit. Nulla eget dictum leo. Curabitur elementum purus non erat pharetra pharetra. Ut et ante eget diam eleifend porttitor. Ut convallis leo ac urna ultricies scelerisque sed ac odio. Phasellus vehicula tempor varius. Donec accumsan ullamcorper ultrices. Maecenas nec luctus arcu. Proin non odio libero. Cras vitae nisi scelerisque, ullamcorper eros volutpat, euismod nibh. Nam diam orci, elementum vel sapien nec, mattis auctor quam.
</textarea>
```

Without any refactoring. Well, a little bit to address multiple textareas correctly

```js
$('textarea').click(function(e) {
  $(e.target).css({
    'height': 'auto',
    'white-space': 'nowrap'
  });
  e.target.scrollLeft 
    = (
        e.target.selectionStart 
        * (
          e.target.scrollWidth / $(e.target).val().length
        )
      ) - 20;
});
$('textarea').blur(function(e) {
  $(e.target).css({
    'white-space': 'normal'
  });
  $(e.target).css({
    'height': e.target.scrollHeight + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
textarea.workingTA {
  resize: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  direction: ltr;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="workingTA" cols="35">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam venenatis congue consequat. Aenean tortor erat, euismod ut elit vitae, placerat efficitur magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus egestas pulvinar lacus nec varius. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce risus risus, luctus eget purus ut, consequat viverra dolor. Pellentesque euismod, nisl eu rhoncus facilisis, ligula ligula fringilla mauris, a tempor tortor mi eget augue. Ut at semper turpis. Fusce lectus lectus, finibus eu imperdiet eget, dictum ac nisl. Aliquam at dapibus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum interdum blandit lectus, id rhoncus dolor imperdiet id. Phasellus condimentum lacinia sapien non mattis. Nulla a lectus nisi. Aenean et nunc vel nibh pulvinar blandit. Nulla eget dictum leo. Curabitur elementum purus non erat pharetra pharetra. Ut et ante eget diam eleifend porttitor. Ut convallis leo ac urna ultricies scelerisque sed ac odio. Phasellus vehicula tempor varius. Donec accumsan ullamcorper ultrices. Maecenas nec luctus arcu. Proin non odio libero. Cras vitae nisi scelerisque, ullamcorper eros volutpat, euismod nibh. Nam diam orci, elementum vel sapien nec, mattis auctor quam.</textarea>

<textarea class="workingTA" cols="35">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam venenatis congue consequat. Aenean tortor erat, euismod ut elit vitae, placerat efficitur magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus egestas pulvinar lacus nec varius. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce risus risus, luctus eget purus ut, consequat viverra dolor. Pellentesque euismod, nisl eu rhoncus facilisis, ligula ligula fringilla mauris, a tempor tortor mi eget augue. Ut at semper turpis. Fusce lectus lectus, finibus eu imperdiet eget, dictum ac nisl. Aliquam at dapibus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum interdum blandit lectus, id rhoncus dolor imperdiet id. Phasellus condimentum lacinia sapien non mattis. Nulla a lectus nisi. Aenean et nunc vel nibh pulvinar blandit. Nulla eget dictum leo. Curabitur elementum purus non erat pharetra pharetra. Ut et ante eget diam eleifend porttitor. Ut convallis leo ac urna ultricies scelerisque sed ac odio. Phasellus vehicula tempor varius. Donec accumsan ullamcorper ultrices. Maecenas nec luctus arcu. Proin non odio libero. Cras vitae nisi scelerisque, ullamcorper eros volutpat, euismod nibh. Nam diam orci, elementum vel sapien nec, mattis auctor quam.</textarea>
```

Comment: I've tried `click()`, but this event will not work properly when there are multiple Textarea  boxes in a single page. Please try using this scenario and let me know your comments.

Comment: BTW, appreciate your reply.

Comment: I've added a second textarea to my snippets and they work. Please be aware, that I did some changes to your use of `jQuery` to address the multiple textarea issues you have

Comment: Not sure how you've tried in multiple boxes scenario. Would I ask you to use, let say 4 textareas (please keep them empty on load) , enter content into them, then, change focus from one textbox to another and see the impact. I see that, when you focus on 1st textbox and jump over to next, the click event is not firing on it. Is it been ignoring in between blur() and focus()?

Comment: I see your problem. I tried to split the click event into a focus part and a click part, but this does not work as well, because the focus event occurs before the click event and thus the selectionStart value is fals for clicking in the second or up row of textarea